# How to redirect to another page or sitecore item in MVC

Tags: mvc

I'm new to MVC and trying to achieve page redirection. User will click on "Sign-out" and should be redirected to the "sign-in" page.
Here is my code.

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
  if (Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn)
  {
    LogoutUser();
    return RedirectToRoute(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = "/en/sign-in" });
  }
}
```

This method is invoked, but the page is redirected to "en/?f" and the message on page is

> This domain is not configured for this service. Please add it to your
>   account.

Should something be configured for routes or in web.config.

Using Sitecore 8.0 update 5

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do page redirection, simply do

```
return Redirect(url);
```

For a permanent redirect (e.g. for search engines), use

```
return RedirectPermanent(url);
```

Both of these return a `RedirectResult` which inherit from `ActionResult`.

To redirect to a Sitecore Item, do it the same way you always have.

```
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(yourItem);
return Redirect(url);
```

Comment: Watch the logs when you do this. I've seen instances of "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent." errors.