# Redirect to a Sitecore Item or Page with ViewModel?

Tags: mvc, mvc-forms

I want to pass a ViewModel to a Sitecore Page from a Controller Action.

So far this below post [Link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4743/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-or-sitecore-item-in-mvc) has helped, but I'm not able to pass a model to the page.

I'm calling the controller from a Form post.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
          {
              @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Search", "Index")
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="@Model.ScheduleLinkUrl" data-fancyscroll="data-fancyscroll"> <span class="nav-link-text">Schedule</span></a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><input type="text" id="searchBox" /><button type="submit">Search</button></li>
          }
```

And inside controller, what I want to have is:

```
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{E2C750EE-7F7D-4A9E-983E-8F04C8CC8B6B}")));
return Redirect(url, model);
```

Can anyone help me out on this?
Thanks, community for the help.

Comment: If i understood correctly your question you are trying an approach similar to the one described https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734601/how-to-redirect-to-a-sitecore-page-with-data-from-controller-action or https://mhwelander.net/2014/05/22/passing-data-between-actions-in-sitecore-mvc/?

Comment: Thanks Cristi. So I can use the below code to redirect to the page with a viewmodel?

`return RedirectToRoute(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = pathInfo.TrimStart(new char[] { '/en/Home/NewPage' }), carID = id });
    }
}
`

Comment: Yes, similar to that, depending on your case. If it works will add it as an answer :)

Comment: @Cristy Yes it works. Thanks, man you are a lifesaver! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we cannot use `RedirectToAction()` in Sitecore MVC as it interrupts the page rendering process, in this case you can use the `RedirectToRoute()`, for example using this approach:

```
var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse("[your item id]"));
var pathInfo = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, UrlOptions.DefaultOptions);
return RedirectToRoute(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = pathInfo.TrimStart(new char[] { '/' }), carID = id });
```

Comment: LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, UrlOptions.DefaultOptions); is returning a string of the type: 
 "/sitecore/templates/feature/.../.."  which is not recognized as a valid URL obviously.